# Why the state of object is not changed aftre first initialization?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I use custom class as library in Laravel:

```
class Settings
{
    public function __construct($data = [])
    {
        $this->settings = Setting::find(Auth::user()->id);
        var_dump($this->settings);
    }
}
```

And call this:

```
$settings = new Settings($request->settings);
$settings->pre_update();
```

When first call constructor I get `var_dump($this->settings); die();` as null, after method `pre_update()` adds data to data.

But after second click, when in data there is data and `$request->settings` should not be `null`.

Why I get `null` after second click?

Maybe all custom classes in laravel works as static?

Comment: `when in data there is data` Why? Do you know what `die` does?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but it could be that `die()` actually ends your process, hence you don't have any data or whatever.

Comment: Add `public function __destruct(){print __METHOD__;}` to see when the object is destroyed.

Comment: Obviously your question title has nothing in common with your question text.

Comment: And to your text, as i understand:  if you have `die();` in your `__construct` the `pre_update` will never called. And the dump is before the update, so without `die();` you still dump the sesttings before the update. after 3 clicks it maybe will show something after you removed `die();`. For more debug add `public function __destruct(){print __METHOD__; var_dump($this->settings);}`

Comment: I dont use die, sorry, updated question